# segmentation fault with SIFT

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

I am trying to decipher why I am getting a segmentation fault when trying to use SIFT.

I am using the test fasta file, and substituion file they provide. I am using the swissport database which I can successfully BLAST against on my system.

Here is what I get when trying to use SIFT:

```
arron@arron-Ideapad-Z570 ~/Phd/programs/sift4.0.3b $ bin/SIFT_for_submitting_fasta_seq.csh test/lacI.fasta db/swissprot.fa test/lacI.subst 2.75
tail is lacI.fasta
query is /home/arron/Phd/programs/sift4.0.3b/tmp/lacI.fasta.query
query length 360
entered read_psiblastuntillat
Segmentation fault
tell me i've entered
info_on_seqs
fawegwa
cannot open file /home/arron/Phd/programs/sift4.0.3b/tmp/lacI.alignedfasta 
Output in /home/arron/Phd/programs/sift4.0.3b/tmp/lacI.SIFTprediction
```

I've been trying for the last two hours to find some source code where the error is handled, but I have been unsuccessful. Does anybody have any experience with SIFT segmentation faults, or are able to point me to the source code so that I can see what is going wrong?

Thanks very much.

Comment: source code for sift: http://siftdna.org/www/sift/public/sift5.2.1.tar.gz although it's for a much newer version (5.2.1 not 4.0.3b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you are using such an old version of SIFT?  I think the latest version is 5.2.1 where you appear to be using 4.0.3b

My guess is you are using a newer version of Blast that is not compatible with the old version of SIFT.

The release notes for sift 5.2 say:

> SIFT 5.2.0 released. Code has been updated to be compatible with later versions of BLAST (tested on 2.2.28+)

So I either suggest using the new version of SIFT or an old version of blast and see if that fixes things.

Comment: also do you know of any way to output the various data that SIFT collects before it puts into it;s classifier e.g. the scores when alinging to secondary/tertiary structure databases? I would like to try my own classifier out but obviously need the data SIFT collects

Comment: @brucezepplin sorry, I've never actually used SIFT